# Calculating percentage value varies between javascript and c#

Tags: c#, javascript, math

I am trying to calculate the percentage value and I need it to be similar between the javascript and c#, but it differs.

For ex.: 8.70 percentage of 85 = 7.394999999999999 in javascript, but in c# its 7.395.

How can I have the javascript to have the same output as c#. Please suggest.

**Edit:**

I am having difficulty in rounding off the value when calculating 8.70% percentage of 85 and 9.25.

The result for 8.70% of 85 should be 7.40, but javascript gives 7.39.
The result for 8.70% of 9.25 should be 0.80 which is fine.

Below is the code I have used in javascript:

```
(85*8.70/100).toFixed(2)
(9.25*8.70/100).toFixed(2)
```

Any inputs please?

Comment: I'm betting C# has the same result; it just happens to render it rounded for you.

Comment: Are you using the `decimal` type in C# ?

Comment: @sniffer, Yes. I am using decimal in c#

Comment: @Prasad Well that's the problem right there. C# `decimal` type is 128 bits while in JavaScript all numbers are `double` floating point types with 64 bits of precision. C# calculations with decimal are more precise and you can't do simulate that in JavaScript *( I guess )* unless you use some external library which might or might not exist :)

Comment: Basically yuo want to round a rounded value... what is the resuult for (85*8.70/100).Tofixed(3).ToFixed(2)? (I don't know if that is even possible, but Tofixed(3) should give 7.395, which should round to 7.40)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [`toFixed(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method which rounds the number to `n` digits after the decimal point:

```
7.394999999999999.toFixed(3);
```

For a complete list methods that are available on numbers, check the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Methods_of_number_instance)

Comment: It would be wise to use the "same rounding method" on both sides (JS and C#).

Comment: @Sniffer, Thanks for the quick answer. I am having difficulty in rounding off the value when calculating the percentage for 2 different values, please check my updated question

Answer (score 1):

In C#, 85d*8.7d/100d gives 7.3949999999999987. On the other hand, 85d/100d*8.7d gives 7.395. If you use the exact same precision data types and arithmetics, the results should be the same, but it's hard to get it right, especially in a multi-platform way. So you should use rounding, just like you should almost always use rounding when you work with floating-point numbers.